# 301 redirects for some of the urls not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We have wrote the 301 rewrite rules in web version as below and it is working fine

```
RewriteRule ^staff-benefit-solutions https://www.sample.com/engage-your-employees/ [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^corporate-benefits https://www.sample.com/engage-your-employees/ [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Below are the 301 rewrite rules for mobile version which i tried as below and its not redirecting

---

```
RewriteRule ^m/staff-benefit-solutions https://www.sample.com/engage-your-employees/  [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^m/corporate-benefits https://www.sample.com/engage-your-employees/ [R=301,L,QSA]
```

In mobile my full urls will come something like this below www.yyy.com/m/staff-benefit-solutions when we open in the mobile browser. This should redirect to https://www.sample.com/engage-your-employees/ . Can someone help on this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is, in which context do you use the RewriteRule - in VirtualHost or in Directory context? I assume in directory context, because you tagged `.htaccess`.

[Apache Module mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) says:

> In per-directory context (Directory and .htaccess), the Pattern is
>   matched against only a partial path, for example a request of
>   "/app1/index.html" may result in comparison against "app1/index.html"
>   or "index.html" depending on where the RewriteRule is defined.

So you need to define your rewrite in the `.htaccess` under your `root` directory and not under your `m` directory.